# how to share video like iPhone default share

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I want to share a video in my app like default share of iPhone video share.
I have written code but its not like iPhone default share

[here are difference between my share function and iPhone default share](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHxQ1.png)

```
 func shareVideo() {

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
        NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory: AnyObject = paths[0]
    let dataPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("saveFileName")

    let URL: String = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(dataPath)
    let someText: String = "A nice song"
    let urlToShare: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(URL, isDirectory: false)
    let dataToShare: [AnyObject] = [someText, urlToShare]
    let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: dataToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact]

    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
}
```